# IE doesn't read .js page

Tags: javascript, html

I have new problem on my new web site :

It works perfectly on Mozilla firefox, Safari and Chrome.
But it doesn't work on IE.

I have jsFunctions.js on my site. When I try to call it on my html page nothing happens on it.

```
function vasat(Lwidth,layerName){

    var winwidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    var winheight = document.body.clientHight;

    var jayeLayer;

    if (winwidth<=Lwidth)
            jayeLayer=0;
    else
            jayeLayer=(winwidth-Lwidth);

    document.getElementById(layerName).style.right = jayeLayer;

}

function ClientWin(layerName){

    var winwidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    var winheight = document.body.clientHight;

    document.getElementById(layerName).style.width = winwidth ;
    document.getElementById(layerName).style.height = winheight ;

}
```

You can visit my html page on [lrcgroup](http://lrcgroup.ir)

when I check whit alert on my js page I didn't see any alert in IE .

Comment: Your page reports errors even on Chrome. Check console logs: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null (index):39
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Comment: In IE, press F12 to see the console, you've got a number of errors as @AntoJurković says. Since you're also including jQuery, try using jQuery for these things.

Comment: when I check whit alert on my js page I didn't see any alert in IE

Answer (score 0):

Use this comment line on top of your HTML Code, it makes javascript run on IE

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

It is optional, but sometimes it will also be helpful based on IE version, add this in head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

Comment: You can also go internet options and check javascript is enabled or not in your IE, if enabled use the line, it works

Comment: Dont know, it works for me, check other things like path of js....is it running fine in other browsers?

Comment: in all browser work well but with some deal when reload page its work